# How to eliminate the gray points in image?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, matlab-figure, image-scaling

I'm working on simulation of micro structure. In my code, the evolution of micro structure is tracked by `imagesc` in MATLAB. In primary steps, the image is normal and is reasonable. But at final steps, some gray points appear.

[image]

Is it possible to prevent them to be shown in `imagesc`?

Comment: I must be getting very old - I can't see any grey points on your image. Could you point one out please?

Comment: The color bar doesn’t have any gray on it either. It seems you need to improve/fix your simulation to prevent those from appearing? Can’t help there, because I see no information about your simulation in your question.